# Finding equation of a line that is perpendicular to another line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the equation of a line that is perpendicular to $2x-3y=1$, with the point $(1/4,-3/5)$. The answer I've got it $60x+40y+9=0$, but I can't figure out how to get there. The one page I pulled up online, tried to do it how hey showed but didn't get anything like that. I did it once, cause reviewing my answer key for this one, it was marked that I got it right, but I can't remember how I got there.

Comment: @mlo Fixed your tag.

Comment: Please do not use a tag without reading the tag excerpt [tag:graph-theory] is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the equation from standard form to slope-intercept form, that is, of the form $y=mx+b$
$$2x-3y=1$$
$$-3y=1-2x$$
$$y=\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}$$

The graph of $y=mx+b$ is a line that has a slope of $m$. In this case, we have $m=\frac{2}{3}$.

Two lines with slope $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ are perpendicular to each other if and only if $m_{1}*m_{2}=-1$. We let $m_{1}=\frac{2}{3}$ and solving for $m_{2}$, we have
$$\frac{2}{3}*m_{2}=-1$$
$$2*m_{2}=-3$$
$$m_{2}=-\frac{3}{2}$$

An equation for a line that passes through a point $(x_{1},y_{1})$ with slope m is 
$$y-y_{1}=m(x-x_{1})$$

We want the perpendicular line with slope $-\frac{3}{2}$ to pass through the point $(\frac{1}{4},-\frac{3}{5})$, thus we let $(x_{1},y_{1})=(\frac{1}{4},-\frac{3}{5})$ and $m=-\frac{3}{2}$, and finally we have
$$
y-\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right) = -\frac{3}{2}\left(x - \frac{1}{4}\right) \\
y + \frac{3}{5} = -\frac{3}{2}x + \frac{3}{8}\\
40y + 24 = -60x + 15 \\
60x + 40y + 9 = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

The slope of $2x - 3y = 1$ is $\frac{2}{3}$. In order for a line to be perpendicular to a line with slope $k$, its slope has to be $-\frac{1}{k}$ (why?). This means that the slope of our line will be $-\frac{3}{2}$.

Now it's simply a matter of finding a line with slope $-\frac{3}{2}$ through the point $(\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{3}{5})$, which is quite simple:
$$
y - \left(-\frac{3}{5}\right) = -\frac{3}{2}\left(x - \frac{1}{4}\right) \\
y + \frac{3}{5} = \frac{-3 x}{2} + \frac{3}{8}\quad \text{(multiply by }40\text{)} \\
40y + 24 = -60x + 15 \\
60x + 40y + 9 = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

All lines perpendicular to $ax + by + c = 0$ have the form $bx - ay + c' = 0$ so you need to find $c$ such that
$$-3x-2y + c = 0 \qquad \text{ for } (x,y) = (\frac14, -\frac35)$$
i.e.
$$-\frac34 + \frac65 + c = 0$$
Finally you can multiply all constants by the least common multiple of the denominators to get integer coefficients for the same line.